# How to pass an array to PHP using $http.delete with AngularJS and Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

In my AngularJS Service I have an array of id's which I want to pass to a PHP server so it can delete them but somehow I keep on getting a **500/Internal Server Error** response.

In my server log it's saying that the request is missing one argument which means the passing to the server wasn't successful.

I have something like this in my service:

```
destroySelected : function (ids) {
  // console.log(ids);
  // return $http.delete('/posts/destroySelected', ids);
  return $http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/posts/destroySelected/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    data: {ids : ids}
  });
}
```

For my php controller I have this:

```
public function destroySelected($ids) {
    echo "<pre>" . var_export($ids, true) . "<pre>";
    die;
    return response()->json(Post::get());
}
```

my route:

```
Route::delete('posts/destroySelected/', 'PostController@destroySelected');
```

It's empty, but I wanted to double check that it's being passed successfully before I do anything else.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong here?

Comment: @jakubwrona that's the original route I tried using with what Georges provided, I added `{post}` to the url and still trying to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provided any data to the controller :)

You have : `url: '/posts/destroySelected/'` and `data: {ids : ids}`

So, your final url will be `/posts/destroySelected/?ids=1` (for example)

The parameter $ids on your request require an url route parameter (for example route `/posts/destroySelected/{ids}`) and not a query parameter (_GET/_POST)

**Solution:**

```
        return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: '/posts/destroySelected/' + ids,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
        });
```

To get the query parameter (_GET), you can use:

```
<?php
public function destroySelected(Request $request) {
    $ids = $request->input('ids'); // will get the value of $_REQUEST['ids'] ($_GET or $_POST)
    // var_dump($request->all()); for all values

    echo "<pre>" . var_export($ids, true) . "<pre>";
    die;
    return response()->json(Post::get());
}
```

Comment: I tried few ways and this was one of them but I think I forgot about the `Request $request` in the first place thanks a lot